# Yii2 Kartik FileUpload : Multiupload initialPreviewConfig JSON data from controller seems doesnt work

Tags: javascript, yii2, yii-extensions, kartik-v

### Before all

- I have model for image as simple as

  ```
  return [
      'id' => 'ID',
      'parent_id' => 'Parent ID',
      'photo' => 'Photo', <= just for filename
  ];
  ```
- the case is
     Create Parent model then save then redirect to form for uploading images related to its parent.
- all uploading function work proprerly but no with delete function

## This is my upload image form

```
echo FileInput::widget([
        'model' => $photo,
        'attribute' => 'photo',
        'options'=>[
            'accept'=>'image/*',
            'multiple'=>true
        ],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['/controller/upload', 'id'=> $parent->id]),
            'initialPreview'=>$pre-initViews-data,
            'initialPreviewAsData'=>true,
            'initialCaption'=>"Foto Tersangka",
            'initialPreviewConfig' => $pre-initConfigs-data,
            'overwriteInitial'=>true, 
            //'deleteUrl'=> Url::to(['/controller/deletephoto']),    <= case 2
            'showPreview' => true,
            'showRemove' => false,
            'showUpload' => false,
            'maxFileSize'=>2800
        ],
        'pluginEvents' => [
            'fileuploaded'=>"function(event, data, previewId, index){
                console.log(data);
            }",
        ]
    ]);
```

## And here my controller side

```
    $imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'photo');

    $directory = Yii::$app->basePath. '/images/';
    if ($imageFile) {
        $fileName = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(). '.' . $imageFile->extension;
        $filePath = $directory . $fileName;
        if ($imageFile->saveAs($filePath) && $model->save(false)) {
            $path = '/images/temp/' . $fileName;
            Image::thumbnail($directory.$fileName, 120, 120)
            ->save(Yii::$app->basePath.$path, ['quality' => 80]);

            $response = [];
            $reponse['initialPreview'] = \Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/images/'.$fileName;
            $reponse['initialPreviewConfig']=[
                'caption'=>'',
                'width'=>'90px',
                'key'=>$model->id,
                'url'=>Url::to(['/controller/deletephoto']),
                'extra'=>['id'=>$model->id]
            ];
            echo json_encode($reponse);
        }
    }
```

And will produce JSON data like this :

```
    {
    "initialPreview": "\/web\/images\/Kl1IJOabLs5ENzzgkuW8ln_TILcDumy9.png",
    "initialPreviewConfig": {
        "caption": "",
        "width": "90px",
        "key": 38,
        "url": "\/web\/index.php?r=controller%2Fdeletephoto",
        "extra": {
            "id": 38
        }
    }
   }
```

### The issue

I try different way like :

- case 1 : 
  at form widget withoud pluginOptions => deleteUrl'=> Url::to(['/controller/deletephoto']), 
  upload process success, response from controller initialPreview overwriting initial as expected, but initialPreviewConfig seems doesnt fit, so delete button doesnt work/ doesnt give any process when clicked.
- case 2 : 
  at form widget with pluginOptions => deleteUrl'=>
  Url::to(['/controller/deletephoto']) , upload process as expected, but when i click delete button post action didnt parse key as below

  Query string
  r : controller/deletephoto
  Form data 
  key : {empty key}

### Finally

Ive spend huge amount of hours, Please review my code, is there something wrong?

a Big thanks for your help.

### UPDATE ISSUE RESOLVED

after long hours finally i got the way..
replace

```
      $response = [];
      $reponse['initialPreview'] = \Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/images/'.$fileName;
      $reponse['initialPreviewConfig']=[
          'caption'=>'',
          'width'=>'90px',
          'key'=>$model->id,
          'url'=>Url::to(['/controller/deletephoto']),
          'extra'=>['id'=>$model->id]
      ];
      echo json_encode($reponse);
```

with

```
        return Json::encode([
            'initialPreview' =>  \Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/images/'.$fileName,
            'initialPreviewConfig' => [
                [
                    'caption'=>'',
                    'width'=>'90px',
                    'key'=>$model->id,
                    'url'=>Url::to(['/controller/deletephoto']),
                    'extra'=>['id'=>$model->id]
                ],
            ],
        ]);
```

dont know why this happen,

Comment: i was unable to re-create the issue at my end do you have a live link to the issue you are talking about?

Comment: hai @MuhammadOmerAslam

I found the answer, i updated above.
Thanks